# Data name not being saved to db using CakePHP Form

Tags: php, sql, forms, cakephp, upload

I am making an admin tool, for the site I am making, that allows the admin to make image uploads to a folder at the server, that stores images for a gallery. The file is being uploaded correctly but the image name isn't being placed on the database. The name should be placed at the table "gallery_images", on the "path" field. How can this be fixed?

I am using CakePHP 2.4.4

**Controller**

```
    <?php
class AdminsController extends AppController{

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public function admin_index(){
        if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
        $this->redirect(array(
                                'controller' => 'admins',
                                'action' => 'login'));
        }
        $this->layout='admin_index';
    }
    public function add_foto() {            
        if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
        $this->redirect(array(
                                'controller' => 'admins',
                                'action' => 'login'));
        }
        $this->layout='admin_index';
        $file=$this->request->data['gallery_images']['path'];
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){
                $this->Admin->create();
            $this->Admin->save($file);
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp_app/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);
                     if($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)){
                     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ficheiro carregado com sucesso!'));
            }
        }
        //$this->Admin->id = $id;
        //$this->Post->save($data=array($this->data['Admins']['path']), $params=array('fieldList'=>'path'));
        //$this->Post->saveField('path', $this->data['Admins']['path']);
            /*if ($this->ModelName->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Data Saved!');
            }*/
        //if($this->request->is('post')){
        //  $this->Admin->save($this->request->data);
            //}
        //}
    }
}
    ?>
```

**View**

```
    <h2>Adicionar Fotografia</h2>
    <?php
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->create('Admin',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('gallery_images.path');
echo "<br>";
//echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');
//validação é feita no AdminsController
    ?>
```

Comment: If you look at your last question regarding cakePHP, you will notice model name should be `GalleryImage`.

Comment: @Skywalker The GalleryImage is for the GalleryImagesController and the Admin model for AdminsController, Admin for admin actions only. Is this made incorrectly?

Comment: Is there any relation between `Admin` and `GalleryImage` models? Read on [Model Assocations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

**Controller**

```
    <?php
    class GalleryController extends AppController {
    
    public function admin_upload_image(){
        $this->layout = 'admin_index';
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
          /*  $file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];*/
        $file = array(
                'GalleryImage' => array(
                'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
                                        )
                );
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp_app/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);

            $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
            $this->GalleryImage->create();
            
            if($this->GalleryImage->save($file)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ficheiro carregado com sucesso!'));
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Erro ao carregar o ficheiro!'));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**View**

```
    <h2>Adicionar Fotografia</h2>
    <?php
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->create('GalleryImage',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('gallery_images.path');
echo "<br>";
//echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');

    ?>
```

**Model**

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class GalleryImage extends AppModel{
    public $displayField ='path';
    public $useTable = 'gallery_images';
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`admins` **db table** is:

- **model** `Admin`, your app file: ../app/Model/`Admin`.php,
- **controller** in your app file: ../app/Controller/`Admins`Controller.php,
- **action/function** `add_foto()` in Your controller AdminsController.php.

`gallery_images` **db table** is:

- **model** `GalleryImage`, your app file: *../app/Model/`GalleryImage`.php*,
- **controller** in  your app file: ../app/Controller/`GalleryImages`Controller.php

Read more about Cake naming conventions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

**1. - SAVE ONE TABLE**

If You want to save data to `gallery_images`, You have to create form for `GalleryImage`, like:

**VIEW:** ../app/View/GalleryImages/**add_foto.ctp**

> ```
>   echo $this->Form->create('GalleryImage', array('type' => 'file')); // << db table gallery_images        
>           // ...
>       echo $this->Form->input('admin_id', array('value' => $admin_id)); // << id of db table admins
>           // ...
>       echo $this->Form->file('path'); // << your field of db table gallery_images
>           // ... 
>   echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');
> ```

**CONTROLLER**: ../app/Controller/**GalleryImagesController.php**

```
public function add_foto() {
    // ...  
    // debug($this->request->data); die(); // << You can see Your data  
    if($this->request->data){
        // ...
        $this->GalleryImage->save($this->request->data);
        // ...
    };
    // ...
}
```

**2. SAVE MANY TABLES**

If You want to save data to db table `admins` and `gallery_images` **in the same time (one form)**. You have to use `$this->YourModelName->saveAll($this->request->data)`, 
read more:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

and You have to define model relations/link models: belongs_to/has_many first, like:

**MODEL**: Admin.php:

```
var $hasMany = array(       
                'GalleryImage' => array(
                    'dependent' => true 
                ),
             );
```

**MODEL**: GalleryImage.php

```
var $belongsTo = array('Admin');
```

Then **VIEW**: .../Admins/**add_foto.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Admin', array('type' => 'file')); // << db table gallery_images
    // ...
    echo $this->Form->input('Admin.id', array('value' => $admin_id)); // << id of db table admins
    echo $this->Form->input('Admin.name');
    echo $this->Form->input('Admin.surname');
    // ...
    echo $this->Form->input('GalleryImage.0.admin_id', array('value' => $admin_id)); // << id of db table admins
    echo $this->Form->file('GalleryImage.0.path'); // << your field of db table gallery_images
    // ... 
    echo $this->Form->input('GalleryImage.1.admin_id', array('value' => $admin_id)); // << id of db table admins
    echo $this->Form->file('GalleryImage.1.path'); // << your field of db table gallery_images
    // ...
echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');
```

And **CONTROLLER**: ../Controller/**AdminsController.php**

```
public function add_foto() {
        // ...      
        if($this->request->data){
            // ...
            $this->Admin->saveAll($this->request->data);
            // ...
        };
        // ...
    }
```

Hope this help.